# namespace ensemble create -map : Get the old name in my procedure when I call it

Tags: tcl

below my namespace :

```
namespace eval ::my {

    namespace ensemble create -map {
        name            name
        newName         name
    }
}
```

and my procedure :

```
proc ::my::name {args} {
    puts [lindex [info level 0] 0]
}
```

I would like to get the name of my procedure, for this I use `[lindex [info level 0] 0]`.
But when I call : `my newName`, It always returns `::my::name`.
Is It possible to get *::my::newName* instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because you are looking at the resolved implementation name. If you want information about the way in which your implementation is called, pass it as an extra argument:

```
namespace eval ::my {
    proc name {realName args} {
        puts $realName
    }
    namespace ensemble create -map {
        name            {name name}
        newName         {name newName}
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of being useful even if an abbreviated subcommand name is used (e.g., `my new`).

Comment: The default wrong-args error messages adapt for you. They use shenanigans to do this. Your scripts do not have access to those.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you may be able to use an [execution trace](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/trace.html#M9):

```
trace add execution my enter [list apply [list {cmd args} {
    if {[lindex $cmd 0] eq "my"} {
        puts [lindex $cmd 1]
    }
}]]
```